# Mouse click origin

Tags: c#, click

I'm working on an analysis about bots.

Is there a way to know if a button click was executed "programmatically" or using a mouse device?

(If the solution is in .Net, it would be fine)
Regards.

Comment: I think you can do this by creating a new event for the mouse( if you can modify the driver of the mouse) and see if the mouse click event it's on the same time with your custom event.

Comment: do you want to do it it windows application.give mode detail

Comment: @irsog : Well, imagine that I have a simple windows form with a button. I want to know if the click was performed with the mouse device or with a simulated click action.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Asp.Net, the AjaxControlToolKit has a nifty control that I find works great:

```
<asp:NoBot ID="NoBot1" runat="server" ResponseMinimumDelaySeconds="10" />
```

Otherwise you could measure the time between time of displaying the form and the return answer, because bots measure responses in milliseconds, us humans are much slower.

For the NoBot control, there is an event `OnGenerateChallengeAndResponse` that you can customize the response.

See this blog post: [The Ajax Control Toolkit NoBot control and session state](http://jlchereau.blogspot.com/2007/10/ajax-control-toolkit-nobot-control-and.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there an alternative for desktop applications ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you can use the Stopwatch class to determine the time between events.